# Praat script to export all possible data about audio

Tags: praat

Maybe someone has the [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting.html) **script**, which can get all possible information about the Audio file (pitches, formats, intensity)?[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "all possible data about audio" you *only* mean fundamental frequency, formant structure and intensity contour (and not, say, spectra, pulses, etc), the easiest way to do this is to generate respectively a [Pitch](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Pitch.html), [Formant](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Formant.html), and [Intensity](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Intensity.html) objects.

```
pitch     = To Pitch: 0, min_f0, max_f0
formant   = To Formant (burg): 0,
  ... total_formants, max_formant, 0.025, 50
intensity = To Intensity: min_f0, 0, "yes"
```

You'll still need to know *some* things about the audio you're processing, though, like the likely frequency of the maximum formant you are interested in, or the range within which you estimate the fundamental to be (you might want to look at [this plugin](http://cpran.net/plugins/twopass/) with automatic methods for estimating f0 range).

As for the exporting, what I assume you mean by this is that you want this information to be accessible from a program that is *not* Praat. This might be the hardest part, since Praat does not have any standard way to *export* data, and the data formats that it uses, although they are all text-based, are all very ... Praat-specific (you can check them out by using the [`Save as text file...`](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Save_as_text_file___.html) command).

You could process them within Praat and put the data you want into a [Table](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Table.html) object with whatever format and structure you want and save it as either a tab or a comma separated file (see my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955938/807650)). To get started, you could use the `Down to Table...` command available for Formant objects, which will create a Table with the formant data. You can then expand that Table to include data from the Pitch and Intensity objects (or whatever objects you need).

Alternatively, most (=not all) text-based formats used by Praat are *almost* YAML, so you could try to convert them and read them *as-is* into whatever program you want to use later on. I wrote a couple of Perl scripts that do just this, converting [to](https://gitlab.com/cpran/plugin_serialise/blob/master/scripts/praat2yaml.pl) and [from](https://gitlab.com/cpran/plugin_serialise/blob/master/scripts/yaml2praat.pl) JSON/YAML, and [a Praat plugin](http://cpran.net/plugins/serialise/) to do this from the Praat GUI. You might want to check those out.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I want to get big table with [time][intensity][formants][pitches] any format (xml, csv, txt)

Comment: Can you provide more code? Easily export to table one LongSound file.

Comment: Short of actually writing your script for you, I can't imagine what more code I can provide: I've pointed out the exact commands you need to obtain formant structure, and fundamental frequency and intensity contours; and I've linked to a question with an extensive example of how to put that into a Table. What more code do you want? There's a `Down to Table...` command for Formant objects that can provide you with a Table to get started; I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script solves the problem.

```
form Give the parameters for pause analysis
   comment soundname:
    text soundname 1.wave   
   comment outputFileName.csv:
    text outputFileName result.csv
endform

min_f0 = 75
max_f0 = 350

Read from file: soundname$
soundname$ = selected$ ("Sound")

select Sound 'soundname$'
formant = To Formant (burg): 0, 4, 5000, 0.025, 50
formantStep = Get time step


selectObject: formant
table = Down to Table: "no", "yes", 6, "yes", 3, "yes", 3, "yes"
numberOfRows = Get number of rows

select Sound 'soundname$'
pitch = To Pitch: 0, min_f0, max_f0

selectObject: table
Append column: "Pitch"

for step to numberOfRows
    selectObject: table
    t = Get value: step, "time(s)"

    selectObject: pitch
    pitchValue = Get value at time: t, "Hertz", "Nearest"

    selectObject: table
    Set numeric value: step, "Pitch", pitchValue
endfor


#export to csv
selectObject: table
Save as comma-separated file: outputFileName$
removeObject(table)

echo Ok
```