# How do I print data with commas separating each element in praat script

Tags: praat

How do I print data with commas separating each element in praat script
I've used here just tab$ but I want to replaced by comma

my statement is:
resultline$ = soundname$+tab$+label$ + tab$ +"'pitchmax:6''tab$''pitchmin:6' 'tab$' 'pitchmean:6' 'newline$'"

any help plz

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer in [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955938/807650). In short: save your values into a Table object, and then save the Table as text using the "Save as comma-separated values..." command.

If you still want to construct each output line yourself, which is probably the least maintainable way to do it... just insert commas between the values you want to print:

```
sep$ = ","
resultline$ = soundname$ + sep$ + label$ + sep$ + "'pitchmax:6'" + sep$ + "'pitchmin:6'" + sep$ + "'pitchmean:6'" + newline$
```